# Modbus RTU/TCP library for .net UWP (universal windows platform)

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, modbus

I am new in modbus communication. Currently i am using Nmodbus and easymodbus library in c# winform application (framework 4.5) and it working fine.

But now i have install Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry PI3. and i created UWP project and successfully deploy in PI3 and it working fine. i already use many modbus library, Like NModbus, EasbyModbus. but it not supporting.

can anybody suggest which library is work for me. 
primary require TCP connection for communication.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[NModbus4](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4) is now based on .Net core in its new versions. Then it should be utilizable in UWP projects.

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable version of NModbus4(2.1.0) supports .Net framework 4.0,it is published at August 9, 2015.So you need to check the .net framework version of your UWP project.If you use the latest version,you can install the prerelease version(3.0.0-alpha2) of NModbus4 package. NModbus4 is fork of [NModbus](https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus), you can also use NModbus to implement the Modbus protocol.